# Does Linux sends `SIGCHLD` to `init` when it inherits orphaned zombie processes?

Tags: linux, signals, init, zombie-process

Does Linux sends `SIGCHLD` to `init` (PID 1 process) when it inherits orphaned zombie processes (processes that have not been reaped by its original parent)?

Comment: just like with any other process, linux will send a `SIGCHLD` to `init` when one of its children has terminated (should that child be spawned by it or adopted). I don't see anything special about it, so maybe you should expand your Q with the actual stuff you find puzzling.

Comment: @mosvy the question here is how does `init` learn about adopted zombies? I think the SIGCHLD was already sent to the parent who failed to reap the zombie?

Comment: @sourcejedi "If it has exited notify the new parent about this child's death" -- just [above](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/kernel/exit.c#L650) the place you link to.

Comment: @mosvy When the live orphaned process dies, yes, but what about if it gets orphaned when it is already dead but not reaped?

Comment: It will send a signal to the new parent, see the link from the comment above. Notice that the new parent is not necessarily init, see the [comment](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/kernel/exit.c#L596) before `find_new_reaper()`. (But the signal will always be `SIGCHLD` -- not the one configured via `clone(2)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep.  I tested it.  And you can see where this happens [in the Linux code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/kernel/exit.c#L650).

---

Test: Start a nested shell.  From elsewhere, `kill -s STOP` the parent shell.  Then `kill -s KILL` the child shell and then the parent.

Note:

If you try this inside `gnome-terminal`, for example, the reaper will not be PID 1.  It will be a sub-reaper, the process `systemd --user`.

Also, `systemd` handles signals using a signalfd.  So when you run `strace -p` on the systemd process, you will not see a signal being received.  You will instead see that systemd wakes from epoll_wait() and performs a read() on a file descriptor.

You can confirm the file descriptor number is a signalfd using `ls -l /proc/<PID>/fd/<FD>`.  It will say `anon_inode:[signalfd]`.

Comment: you don't see it in the code because there's nothing special about it. there's no difference between the SIGCHLD sent to init and the SIGCHLD sent to another process, or between its natural and adopted children.

Comment: @mosvy hmm, if that's the case, how does `init` learn about adopted zombies? I think the SIGCHLD was already sent to the parent who failed to reap the zombie?

Comment: @mosvy edited, thanks for your update in the question comments.